# ssh ec2 instance in Private subnet of another vpc without using bastion

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-vpc, private-subnet

Can anybody let me know if below can be achieved without Bastion.

I have 2 vpc's VPC - A and VPC -B both have private and public subnets(no overlaping CIDRS)
Client VPN endpoint configured with VPC -A and there is vpc peering connection between the two vps's

Now, after connecting to VPN, Can I ssh into ec2 instance in private subnet of VPC -B(without bastion), if yes, what all config required?

Comment: What's the rational behind doing this?

Comment: to access private resources with private address.

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: Tried... didnt work

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to have a route to and from that subnet available. So VPC A and B both need configuration in their route tables and ACLs that allow request from your address (private address acquired after VPN connection) to your private instances at port 22.